# How to show navigation fly-out menu without sibling sites?

Tags: navigation

Is there a way to show a fly-out menu only for the current site, without its sibling sites showing in the navigation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to the site you want to change, then hit Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Navigation.  From there try the various options for Global Navigation or Current Navigation in order to get the desired result.